# How can I create an empty object field?

Tags: c#, object

I need to code a rogue-like game as a project, but I have a slight problem. There is a time I need to choose between which object to create using a switch. I want to declare an "empty" object outside of the switch and the switch then fills the object with values. This is kind of what I want to do:

```
Console.WriteLine("What race would you like to be?")

int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Object heroRace; // This is where the problem comes in

switch(answer)
{
    case 1: heroRace = new Orc(); break;
    case 2: heroRace = new Elf(); break;
}
```

I want `heroRace` to be outside of the switch scope for re-usage. It would greatly simplify my program if I could create something like that.

Comment: you need to cast the object before instanciating it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast the object to more concrete type before accessing it's members

```
Object o=new Orc();
((Orc)o).methodNameWithinOrc();
```

But this can lead to casting exception.

For example..

```
  ((Elf)o).methodNameWithinOrc();
```

would lead to a casting exception because `o` is an object of `Orc` not `Elf`.

It's better to check if the object belongs to a particular class before casting using `is` operator

```
 if(o is Orc)
((Orc)o).methodNameWithinOrc();
```

---

`Object` itself is not useful unless you override the `ToString`,`GetHashCode`.. methods

It should be like

```
 LivingThingBaseClass heroRace;
```

`Orc` and `Elf` should be subclass of `LivingThingBaseClass`

`LivingThingBaseClass` can contain methods like `move`,`speak`,`kill`..All or some of these methods would be overridden by `Orc` and `Elf`

`LivingThingBaseClass` can be an `abstract` class or even an `interface` depending upon your requirement

Comment: +1, but I think you should switch the two halves of your answer around and begin with the `LivingThingCaseClass` and mention that the `object` approach is more like something of a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

General approach would be:

```
interface IRace  //or a base class, as deemed appropriate
{
    void DoSomething();
}

class Orc : IRace
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do things that orcs do
    }
}

class Elf : IRace
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do things that elfs do
    }
}
```

Now heroRace will be declared (outside switch) as:

```
IRace heroRace;
```

And within switch you can:

```
heroRace = new Orc(); //or new Elf();
```

And then...

```
heroRace.DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class test1 
    {
        int x=10;
        public int getvalue() { return x; }
    }
    class test2 
    {
        string y="test";
       public  string getstring() { return y;}

    }
    class Program
    {

        static object a;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 1;
            int x;
            string y;
            if (n == 1)
                a = new test1();
            else
                a = new test2();

            if (a is test1){
               x = ((test1)a).getvalue();
               Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
            if (a is test2)
            {
                y = ((test2)a).getstring();
                Console.WriteLine(y);
            }
        }
    }
```